# C++ - Microsoft Iot Core allowing TCP through firewall for server

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, windows-10-iot-core

I have bought the Raspberry Pi 3 and I am trying to use a socket server on the startup, but nothing happens when I try to connect to the server via telnet.

I know the code works perfectly fine because I copied it over to a regular Win32 application (the allow through firewall came up, i accepted) and it worked perfectly fine.

On my did powershell and used this command to allow it through, the return value was OK, but when I tried to connect via telnet it still didn't work:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Port 9000" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=9000
```

This is my code:

```
    void StartupTask::Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance^ taskInstance)
{ 

    WSADATA WsaData = { 0 };
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &WsaData);

    ADDRINFOW hints = { 0 }, *results = nullptr;
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    GetAddrInfoW(nullptr, L"9000", &hints, &results);
    SOCKET hSocket = socket(results->ai_family, results->ai_socktype, results->ai_protocol);
    bind(hSocket, results->ai_addr, static_cast<int>(results->ai_addrlen));
    listen(hSocket, 0);

    char RecvBuffer[500];
    SOCKET hConnection = INVALID_SOCKET;
    hConnection = accept(hSocket, nullptr, nullptr);
    while (true)
    {
        send(hConnection, "Hello!", 7, 0);
        recv(hConnection, RecvBuffer, 500, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: `WSADATA WsaData = { 0 };
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &WsaData);` is only on the Windows side, yes?

Comment: @user4581301 He is using Windows 10 IoT Core on the RP3.

Comment: Windows on Pi. Wasn't expecting that. Didn't see the tag either.